# how to display data using where condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a problem that I want to display data using use conditions by this column in ON clause for status_riwayat=keluar AND display data that status_riwayat=masuk not using colomn tanggal conditin like below.

table supplier

```
CREATE TABLE pj_detailsupplier (
id_detailsupplier int,
id_barang int,
id_supplier int,
no_batch varchar(255),
stok int,
tanggal date,
tgl_expired date,
status_detailsupplier int );

  INSERT INTO `pj_detailsupplier`(`id_detailsupplier`, `id_barang`, `id_supplier`, `no_batch`, `stok`, `tanggal`, `tgl_expired`, `status_detailsupplier`) VALUES ('13208','205','25','1','12','2022-01-01','2022-01-01','0')
```

table history

```
 CREATE TABLE pj_riwayat (
 id_riwayat int,
 id_detailsupplier int,
 jumlah int,
 keluar int,
 sisa int,
 tanggal date,
 status_riwayat varchar(255) );

 INSERT INTO `pj_riwayat`(`id_riwayat`, `id_detailsupplier`, `jumlah`, `keluar`, `sisa`, `tanggal`, `status_riwayat`) VALUES ('','13208','12','0','12','2022-09-02','masuk'), ('','13208','0','2','10','2022-11-14','keluar')
```

I want to display data from status_riwayat=masuk and status_riwayat=keluar but using where condition

I have tried my code

```
  SELECT * FROM pj_riwayat
  LEFT JOIN pj_detailsupplier ON pj_riwayat.id_detailsupplier=pj_detailsupplier.id_detailsupplier 
  AND month(pj_riwayat.tanggal)=11 AND year(pj_riwayat.tanggal)=2022 
  WHERE pj_detailsupplier.id_barang=205
```

but this code is still false because I use conditions by this column in ON clause. I wish to display data that status_riwayat=masuk AND status_riwayat=keluar

the result of my code only display one data

[image]

I want the desire result is display two data like below by using my query above

[image]

Comment: *I use where condition in colomn tanggal.* - no, you use conditions by this column in ON clause.

Comment: Provide sample data not as a picture but as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: But where are CREATE TABLE? or you want us to imagine them?

Comment: Also - the desired output must match shown sample data completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need in this:

```sql
SELECT t2.*, t3.*
          -- find id_detailsupplier which matches 
          -- id_barang=205 and tanggal=2022-11-XX
FROM pj_riwayat t1
JOIN pj_detailsupplier t2
  ON t1.id_detailsupplier=t2.id_detailsupplier 
          -- select all rows with found id_detailsupplier
          -- from another table copy
JOIN pj_riwayat t3
  ON t1.id_detailsupplier=t3.id_detailsupplier 
WHERE t2.id_barang=205
  AND month(t1.tanggal)=11
  AND year(t1.tanggal)=2022 
  AND t3.status_riwayat IN ('masuk', 'keluar')
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/upv6Kc4A

Comment: I try to add 3 data in table pj_riwayat than it display double data sir.

Comment: @SukmoAbadii Edit the fiddle, add needed data, provide the link and explain what is the incorrectness.

Comment: I have solved it by using group by @akina. thanks for your respons